# MS Edge How to use command+D to Select the URL in the address bar to edit

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge

MS Edge How to use command+D to Select the URL in the address bar to edit

MS Edge use

> command+D

to Save your current tab as a favorite. Which I don't use it. But its cmd+D is near

However, the universal 'Open Location' shortcut is Cmd ⌘ L

Is there uncomplicated way to make it work?

I use macOS with mac keyboard

ref.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-edge-50d3edab-30d9-c7e4-21ce-37fe2713cfad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The universal 'Open Location' shortcut is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  <kbd>L</kbd>  
The universal command for 'Bookmark This Page' is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd> 
The wording may change slightly between browsers, but all use the same commands.

This applies to Safari, Chrome, Firefox & Edge.
Chrome is the same as all the others in this respect. To have  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd>  as Open Location, you must have already changed this, as below.

You can change these either globally or on a per app basis in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts but only if you can *exactly* match the wording in the menu. Safari & Chrome use the same text, Firefox doesn't have them as menu items so can't be changed, Edge uses different wording so would need to be set up separately.

Comment: +1 For noticing it was Mac not Windows.